# viewing/editing .vsd files in ubuntu

Tags: visio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I open Visio files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6200/how-do-i-open-visio-files)

Can anyone suggest a program which can open MS Visio .vsd files for editing in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (and I've researched this for somebody else before), there are no desktop apps that can open Visio VSDs on Linux. Even Visio under Wine seems to struggle.

However, there is [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/). It's a webservice that converts lots of documents. You just have to give them the file, tell them what you want in return and give them an email address. Might sound fishy but they're under UK privacy law, which despite our government, is actually pretty strict. [Their privacy policy](http://www.zamzar.com/privacy.php) explicitly says they don't sell on your details or documents.